# Are online poker sites rigged?

Tags: online, poker-theory, cheating

This guy tries to prove they are not http://www.thepokerbank.com/articles/online/rigged/
but in the comments everybody says the opposite

So are they rigged or not?

Comment: No, this is only bad players blaming the sites for being so aggros. You need to ask serious players and not donks. _Greg_, the guy behind `thepokerbank` is one of the serious guys, the guys that stream their games on `twoplustwo` forums are the serious, winning guys. Everyone else that cries out loud about bad beats is a bad loser.

Comment: just my personal opinion, online poker is full of cheats. It is to easy to cheat at online poker. Nobody should consider it a safe place to play, unless of course they know all the ins and outs of cheating. Have fun do not put serious money online. The players cheat, the sites are not rigged, they just can't stop players from cheating.

Comment: Your question is very vague and general, your essentially asking for an opinion. It is also a duplicate and been answered in different ways here at poker SE. If you can come up with something more specific I am sure we could answer it. That's why I down voted it. Not really on topic.

Comment: "Rigged" implies that the site owners themselves are the cheats, and I think that's unlikely. You are, however, 100% guaranteed to be cheated by other players.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have over 1M hands in my poker database and everything holds true for the RnG of any site. Stats I can look up are frequency I get hands like AA and odds of calling and shoving all in's. Everything is fine and well within the norm.

The RnG is the same for all, there are no juiced hands. As vlzvl says if you lose regularly then the only person to blame is yourself.

As for cheating and bots, it happens but it's only a small part of the problem. Worry about making correct decisions rather than looking for things that may or may not be there.